# <div> обновляется только после выполнения цикла

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var numbers = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

function randomGenerate() {
  var el1 = document.getElementById("wrap");
  var str = '';
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    minNum = -9999;
    maxNum = 9999;
    randomNum = Math.round((Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum) + minNum));
    numbers[0][i] = randomNum;
    numbers[1][i] = i;
    str += '<div id="bubble_' + i + '" class="bubble" style="left:' + 110 * i + 'px">' + randomNum + '</div>';
  }
  el1.innerHTML = str;
}

randomGenerate();
console.log(numbers[0]);
console.log(numbers[1]);

function swapNumbers(j) {
  m = numbers[0][j];
  var c = numbers[1][j];
  var el1 = document.getElementById("bubble_" + c);
  numbers[0][j] = numbers[0][j + 1];
  numbers[1][j] = numbers[1][j + 1];
  var el2 = document.getElementById("bubble_" + numbers[1][j]);
  numbers[0][j + 1] = m;
  numbers[1][j + 1] = c;
  var x = el2.style.left;
  el2.style.left = el1.style.left;
  el1.style.left = x;
  console.log('Меняемс');

}

function sorting() {
  async = false;
  n = numbers[0].length;
  var chk = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
      if (numbers[0][j] > numbers[0][j + 1]) {
        // setTimeout(swapNumbers(j),10000000000000000000000000);
        delay(200);
        swapNumbers(j);
        el3 = document.getElementById("wrap");
        chk = true;
      }
      // if(chk){break;}
    }
    // if(chk){break;}
  }
  console.log(numbers[0]);
  console.log(numbers[1]);
}

function delay(x) {
  var d = new Date();
  var c, diff;
  while (1) {
    c = new Date();
    diff = c - d;
    if (diff > x) break;
  }
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  width: 1120px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: aqua;
  align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.bubble {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #b1d6ff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

.btnSort {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap" class="wrap"></div>
<button id="btnSort" class="btnSort" onclick="sorting()">Отсортировать</button>
```

Код создан для анмированной сортировки 10 чисел пузырьком, проблема возникла в том, что во время исполнения скрипта дивы не отрисовываются на каждом шагу цикла, а отрисовывается уже тогда, когда функция сортировки окончена.

Comment: Потому что цикл работает без задержок

Comment: перенеси в цикл el1.innerHTML = str; ( в конце перед закрытием скобки) и посмотри, что получится

Comment: Ну так у вас div добавляется уже после цикла, когда отработают все итерации.

Comment: @СергейПетрашко Попробовал, ничего не изменилось